# Simple javascript query on strings and if tests

Tags: javascript, string

I have been "dumped" with resoling this issue -
I have an inbound string which may be, say "123", or "  123".  Either way, my system is expecting "123" so I need to test the first two characters for two spaces and if that's true then I need to return a substring from char 3, length 3.  If there are no spaces I need to return the string.
This is my code, which I know is rubbish, but so far it's all I've managed:
`enter code here

```
`{
    var Code = inString
    return inString.toString().substring(startPosition, endPosition)
    if (inString = "  ") return Code.toString().substring(startPosition,endPosition)
}
```

So you can you what I'm trying to do, I hope.  Believe me, I shouldn't have to do this...  the first part of this is finding the two spaces OK, but the second part isn't finding the "123".  And then after hopefully getting an answer to this I'll then have to work out how to return "123" when there aren't any spaces...
Many thanks

Comment: Are you trying to remove all spaces from the string or just the first position?

Comment: Do you need to trim the string (remove begin and end spaces)? strings have the `trim` method...

Comment: Thanks - what I need to do is trim the string only if the leading spaces are there.  In my inbound file I will have some rows where the string will include the spaces and some where it won't... e.g.  first row contains abc123 and second row contains abc  123, if you see what I mean, and what I need is 123 in both cases, hence the need for an if test

Answer (score 1):

This will remove all spaces from the sting:

```js
var myString = ' a bc d e fgh';
var nospaces = myString.replace(/\s/g,'');
console.log( nospaces );
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to achieve this.

If all you are trying to do is to remove the leading spaces you can do this
Trim leading spaces

```
const trimmedString = inString.replace(/^\s+/g,"");
```

or

```
const trimmedString = inString.trim(); //To remove both leading and trailing spaces
```

This will make a string like "  12345" => "12345" by removing the leading spaces.
If you need only the first 3 characters after this you can do

```
const trimmedFirst3Chars = trimmedString.substring(0,3)
```

If you are only searching for 123 anywhere in the string you can just do

```
const found = inString.contains("123"); // This returns true or false
```

or using Regex

```
const found = /123/g.test(inString);
```

To retrieve the matches you can use

```
const matches = inString.match(/123/g);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `string.trim()` to remove all spaces from the start and end of the string

`var code = inString.trim()`